# How to decouple my data layer better and restrict the scope of my unit tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, architecture

I'm getting to grips with unit testing and learning how to break up my code into testable bits, but one thing I'm not clear on is how I can write my 'higher-level' code, such as my controller actions, so that testing the controller doesn't require going through the actual data layer (which is independently tested elsewhere in my test suite).

For example - I have a user validation which takes a username/password and validates their account and returns login success/failure:

```
class Api_AuthController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
  public function validateUserAction()
  {
    // extract, clean and validate $username from POSTed data
    // extract, clean and validate $password from POSTed data

    // access the data layer
    $accountMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_Account();
    $accounts = $accountMapper(find(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

    if (count($accounts) == 1) {
      // success
    } else {
      // failure
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned - `Application_Model_Mapper_Account` and its `find()` method have been tested in another unit test, so it's superfluous (and as I understand unit testing - undesirable, not to mention it's unnecessarily slowing down my tests) to test again here, as all I really need to test is the ability of the action to discriminate the two possible results of the find function.

So - how do I substitute mocks for the mapper and model into this action so I can limit the scope of the validateUserAction tests?

Comment: lol, no problem.  I just changed the one single-quote so that it made your code format properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from the .net world, but we use [Inversion of Control containers to allow us to inject any dependencies](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) into the controller.  This way you can mock any dependencies to behave how you want and focus your testing on the actions.

Comment: hmm.. so, in Zend there is a [Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html) singleton - would that be suitable for the IoC container?

Comment: @HorusKol: I wish I could help you there, but I know next to nothing about Zend.  Let me see if I can find out.

Comment: @HorusKol: [This link](http://www.ibuildings.co.uk/blog/archives/1181-Dependency-Injection-and-Zend-Framework-Controllers.html) is a little old, but it appears to cover the topic.  Best of luck.